# Google Apps Script HTML Services: Scroll to top of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I have a form that once submitted I would like it to scroll the browser up to the top so the use can see the 'Thanks for submitting!' message. I have tried:

```
window.scrollto(0,0);
```

and also:

```
$('#wrapper').scrollTop();
```

Does Google allow you to reposition the browser in HtmlServices? Anyone have a working example?

Regards,

Shawn

Comment: If anyone has an alternative way of doing this I would be open to it. At this point I am thinking of just using an alert box or something to let the user know his submission was completed in a clear way.

Comment: So I just used an alert box for now. I would be really curious to see how others are handling form or other type submission that the html breaks the fold of the page before the button is reached.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with anchor for backwards compatibility ...

```
<a id='top' href="#"></a>
```

Then in javascript :

```
window.location.hash = '#top';
```

You can also use scroll into view :

```
var div = document.getElementById("top");
div.style.display = 'block';
div.scrollIntoView(true);
```

Hope it help you

Comment: So have you actually gotten this to work in an embedded apps script using htmlservices? I tried both but the code execution just stops when it it hits the window.location.hash = '#top'; and also div.style.display = 'block'.

Comment: It is pretty unclear what type of window methods/properties you can use but I think a lot of them are prevented from running when Caja goes through the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented the form through an iframe, just add this within the tag:

```
onload="window.scrollTo(0,0)"
```